# Disable neovim errors and messages on first start?

Tags: neovim, packer

I am trying to write bash and powershell script to auto install my neovim, for linux/macOS/windows platform.

In a previous step, I will git clone the packer.nvim package.

Then in the last step, I will call `PackerInstall` from nvim, to install all plugins.

Here's the last step script:

bash:

```
nvim -E -c "PackerInstall" -c "qall"
```

powershell:

```
cmd /c nvim -E -c "PackerInstall" -c "qall"
```

But this script seems stuck when installing. There are lots of errors because I specified lots of plugins in `lua/plugins.lua`, and on first start, these plugins are not exist.

How could I ignore/skip/auto-confirm these messages on start?

Answer (score 0):

### Ensure `Packer` is installed

[Packer Quickstart](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim#quickstart)

### Install plugins

`Packer` appears to be async and isn't blocking.  Remove `+qa` and wrap the command in a `timeout`

```bash
timeout 15 nvim +PackerSync --headless 2> /dev/null
```

unix [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html)

- on macos `brew install coreutils`

windows [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/timeout)